# Update any of a number of fields in an SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to optionally update any of a number of fields in an SQL statement?  I can only get so far as something like:

```
UPDATE Customer SET 
    ContactName = ?  <=== what to do here if ? is null???
,   CompanyName = ?  <=== what to do here if ? is null???
,   AddressId   = ?  <=== what to do here if ? is null???
,   ...
WHERE CustomerId = ?
```

It must be a single statement due to a limitation of the wrapper layer and MySQL.

To clarify, I want to create one statement which will be run with one or more non-null values for the fields listed and will update only those fields where the value is not null, leaving the others alone.

This is for a RESTful update API where I don't want a separate statement for every possible combination of fields and I don't want to demand that the API caller supply every single field on the record, which would be unwieldy and would not be future-proof (adding a field breaks existing API calls).  And because it's a REST API I am looking to map `POST /customer/xxx?ContactName=...&CompanyName=...` to update the record.

Comment: If `ContactName` is `NULL`, what's the big deal? Or do you mean "How can I update only the fields that have assigned values?" What application programming language are you using to execute these queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely clear on your goal, but I think you're looking for the [coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) feature; it will return the first non-null value:

> mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,1); -> 1
>
> mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,NULL,NULL); -> NULL

So you can set a 'default' to use in case the value is null:

```
UPDATE Customer SET 
    ContactName = COALESCE(?, <Some default>)
...
```

If you don't want to change the field, just use the current value:

```
UPDATE Customer SET 
    ContactName = COALESCE(?, ContactName)
```

Comment: No, I don't want to default, per se, I want to leave the fields for which no value is provided as they currently are... unless there's a way to make `<some default>` equal the current field value?

Comment: @ManicCoder Then you can just set the default to the current value

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would want to use the existing value if the parameter is null in an update:

```
UPDATE Customer SET 
    ContactName = COALESCE(?,ContactName)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Customer SET 
    ContactName = ifnull(?,ContactName)
,   CompanyName = ifnull(?,CompanyName)
,   AddressId   = ifnull(?,AddressId)
WHERE CustomerId = ?
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d24cd/1/0)